# How do I upload a zip file to a github release in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-upload, github, github-api

I'm trying to automate uploading a zip file to a release on a repo on github. I'm using [github_api](https://github.com/peter-murach/github) to interact with Github's api. I can create a release via that library, but when I try to upload my zip file only the first 425 bytes are transferred. Here's my code related to uploading the file:

```
files = Dir["<dir_containing_zipefile>"]
  files.each do |file|

  github.repos.releases.assets.upload "Owner", "Repo", id, File.absolute_path(file),
    name: "#{File.basename file}",
    content_type: "application/zip"
end
```

I get the `id` from a previous request and have ensured that is correct. I've also ensured that the file found is the correct file (both basename and absolute_path). The request succeeds, but the file uploaded is only a partial of the entire file.

File on system:

[image: file on disk]

File after upload to github release:

[image: file uploaded to github]

After downloading the file from github, I noticed that the 425 Bytes are the first 425 Bytes of my build.zip, but then it seems to get truncated. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Are you sure it's the first 425 bytes?  Have you downloaded it to see?  It's not something like you're uploading the absolute path as the file data or anything?

Comment: Yes, I've compared the original zip file to the downloaded file. The first 425 bytes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Net::HTTP`

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

def attach(url, zipFilePath)
  data = File.open(zipFilePath, "rb") { |f| f.read }
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{YOUR_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
  request.content_type = 'application/zip'
  request.body = data
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, { use_ssl: true }) { |http| http.request(request) }
  return JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```